# Visual selection highlighting invisible (with Evil and color-theme)

Tags: themes, evil

In Emacs color-theme libraries, which items control the visual selection foreground and background?

I'm in the process of giving Emacs a try after many years of Vim use.  The vim emulator, Evil, is working imporessively well for me but I'm having trouble with visual selection highlighting.  The problem seems to be with my chosen color theme rather than with Evil. I say this because if I comment out the the theme I can see the selected text properly highlighted, but not with my chosen theme which is a port of the ir-black them I use in Vim.

I got the theme from https://github.com/jmdeldin/ir-black-theme.el/blob/master/ir-black-theme.el

Here's the section in my .emacs file that loads Evil and the theme.

```
;Enable "Evil", the Vim emulation package
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/evil")
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
(line-number-mode t)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme-6.6.0")
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-ir-black)
```

I've searched color-theme-ir-black.el for "visual" and find only the following lines that seem possibly relevant.

```
;;visual selection: #1D1E2C
 (region ((t (:background "#1D1E2C"))))
 (speedbar-file-face ((t (:foreground "#1D1E2C"))))
```

FWIW, I'm running GNU Emacs 24.4.1 on OS X 10.9.5

Comment: Why are you loading it with `color-theme`? Starting from 24, [emacs has a built-in color theme manager](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Custom-Themes.html), which is what `ir-black-theme` in your link is using. So you load it with `(load-theme 'ir-black)` (and add its path to `custom-theme-load-path`). Does doing this address the problem at all?

Comment: FWIW, I'm using `evil` and can confirm that `region` is what controls the visual selection you're describing.

Comment: @Kirill That doesn't seem to work.  I tried (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path  "~/.emacs.d/color-theme-6.6.0/themes")
(load-theme 'ir-black) and got a complaint that it couldn't find the theme.

Comment: @Dan, Thanks, but changing the value for region seems to have no effect. The theme loads but selection highlights are still invisible.  Think I'm just going to go with another theme that's close to what I want and live with it for now.

Comment: But `ir-black` in the link that you posted *is not an old-style color-theme*, you are doing something strange, I think. Try this: remove all mentions to `color-theme`, download the link you posted (`ir-black-theme.el`) into `~/.emacs.d`, and run `(load-theme 'ir-black)`. I think `color-theme` is obsoleted by Emacs's custom themes.

Comment: FWIW, you shouldn't be using the `color-theme` package, especially not in combination with `load-theme`. Get rid of that part of that config and see whether that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
(custom-theme-set-faces 'ir-black
  `(region ((t :background "magenta"))))
```

in your emacs config somewhere after initializing the theme.